# Draw vector-graphics on PDF using iTextSharp (filling paths with holes)

Tags: c#, itext, vector-graphics

I draw some paths from svg to pdf using iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte methods: moveTo, LineTo and CurveTo. It's works fine for simple paths, but some paths has a cutted square.
For example

```
<path
   style="fill:#1034ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
   d="m 128.5625,106.65625 c -54.285714,37.14286 -54.285714,174.28571 0,260 100,51.42857 434.29464,34.28571 511.4375,0 31.42857,-31.42857 25.71429,-217.14286 0,-260 -31.42857,-34.285714 -460.00893,-42.857143 -511.4375,0 z M 611.4375,232.375 c -1.10965,39.4333 -70.01443,99.97768 -150,71.40625 -78.01486,-27.86748 -164.28571,16.61409 -150,-71.40625 6.31987,-38.93939 67.15729,-71.4375 150,-71.4375 75.65298,0.52477 151.5294,17.08767 150,71.4375 z"
   id="rect3774"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccssccs" />
```

current path has a m=moveto and c=curveto points finished by z=closepath. Next M, C and Z cut a hole in the figure.

How I can draw it in PDF using iTextSharp? How I can cut some inner path from existing path for filling it by ContentByte.Fill();?

Comment: *How I can draw it in PDF using iTextSharp?* - Do you mean in detail or did you just need the even/odd filing hint by Bruno?

Comment: Yes, I just need hint about EoFill and Bruno gived me answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the star shapes on the first row of [figure 14.2](http://www.flickr.com/photos/itextinaction/4484123614) of my book.

The first shape is filled using the `Fill()` method. This method uses the *nonzero winding number rule* to determine whether or not a shape should be filled. Reading your question, I assume that you want to use the *even-odd rule*, in which case you need to use the `EoFill()` method instead of the `Fill()` method.